# How to use libraries in C++?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, libraries

Hello I'm new to coding in C++, thankfully I'm quickly learning how to use it. So far I've heard of libraries and how they can be used in an application.

My questions <s>is</s> are:

1. What do I need to do after I download **ANY** library?
2. How do I `#include "library.h"` or `#include <library>` and use it
   in a project without intellisense or the compiler going nuts?
3. What if the library is header only?
4. What should I look for?
5. Are there any apps I need?
6. What if there's no build folder?

Usually the instructions are unclear to me, maybe it's because I'm still green.

Please try to explain this in an easy to follow manner like if you were teaching it to someone that knows NOTHING: I've tried to follow other guides but with no luck.

Beforehand, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's header-only, including the header is enough. Otherwise, a library can be any piece of code in any form (source in various languages, binary, shared, static, ...). It's impossible to cover all the cases, each library is supposed to come with its own documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your response llya, so if it's header only I should just copy/paste the header I need into the project?

Comment: You have to put the header file in a place where the compiler will find it, then `#include` the header in the files that are using it.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do that in Qt?

Comment: It's not specific to Qt. If you put lib.h in the same directory than your cpp file, `#include lib.h` is enough.

Comment: @IllusionMusic It sounds like you're interesting in installing Qt *specifically*. If so, you should check out their 'Getting Started' page here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html

Comment: Thank you very very much! This so far has been the best help regarding header only libraries!

Comment: Specifically for Qt Creator (if you're using it), there's tools in the GUI to help for other (not header-only) cases: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html

Comment: Have you tried to put the boost dir outside of your project dir ?

Comment: @Laserbreath I'm trying to include a library in a project. The Boost asio library happens to be header only. I pasted it into the app folder and included `#include <boost/asio/async_result.hpp>` intelliense doesn't say it's wrong but when I try to build/debug I get this "mingw32-make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../untitled2/boost/async_result.hpp', needed by 'debug/main.o'.  Stop." this is driving me crazy :/ BTW, thanks for the edits I appreciate them :)

Comment: @Ilya that I saw earlier while doing some research. However some libraries aren't always .a or .lib. Are all libraries built the same way? Usually the README files, as suggested below by Paul Evans aren't the most friendly

Comment: @Ilya yes, I have it in C:\Libraries\boost_1_60_0\boost\asio and I try `#include <C:\Libraries\boost_1_60_0\boost\asio\async_result.hpp>` or `#include "C:\Libraries\boost_1_60_0\boost\asio\async_result.hpp"` and get with the same error

Comment: ...and did you remove the boost files from your project dir ?

Comment: I tried it with the boost files in the project dir and got the same error. Then tried it without them in the project dir, aka in my "C:\libraries\boost..." and got the same error. I think the error is because I'm including it but not using it or does it matter if I include it and not use?

Comment: If they are no more in the project dir, and you're re-run qmake and cleaned everything, I don't see why the IDE would try to build them. But maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Each and every library has a specific license (*eg* MIT, GPL, LGPL *etc*) for it's use.  There can be differences between uses (*eg* personal, academic and commercial *etc*) but often not. It's quite easy to learn about the major licenses and how they might apply to your use case on the internet.  But if you are doing this for commercial purposes or have any doubt whatsoever **consult a lawyer**.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but how do I use a library in a project after I download it?

Comment: If it's not a legal question, then simply follow the install directions,  Start by reading the file called `README`

Comment: You're addressing the licensing part. But what I really need help with is how to I guess _build_ the library and use it in a project or what to do if there's only header files. Thanks though